# Integrate any printer with squareup API - Point of sale system/ KDS

Tags: point-of-sale, square, pos

Can I integrate any printer with square API? 
In documentation, nothing is mentioned other than `Star` printers.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: In theory you could, but it would involve either reverse (or forward) engineering the printer protocols.

Comment: @tristansokol how can i reverse engineer it for IOS/Android?

Comment: You afent going to be able. I would find a new way to integrate using the existing APIs or wait until the functionality you want is released

Comment: How would you integrate with existing API. Any good explanation for that?

Comment: You could poll Incoming transactions for a simar effect

Comment: Square is already installed on Android/IOS devices and I need to write the utility where i can check all http calls from server and do actions accordingly.